# ImportError: No module named matplotlib in virtualenv

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, virtualenv

I am trying to import `matplotlib` while working in my virtualenv for cv.

I can import it just fine in the shell when I import it outside virtualenv but importing it while working on cv, causes this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you installed `matplotlib` in the virtualenv?

Comment: Have you done a `pip install matplotlib` within the virtualenv. How did you create the venv? How do you access python and pip within the virtualenv?

Comment: I followed the instructions on this page to create the virtualenv: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/. And I don't think I installed it within the virtualenv

Comment: *And I don't think I installed it within the virtualenv*. You have installed `matpoltlib` in the virtualenv, just `cd`  and `pip install matpoltlib` and it would be installed as global python package

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it in this way.

I am using virtualenvironment with virtualenvwrapper and running the `import matplotlib` in a Jupyter notebook

I create a virtualenvironment called `test1` with

`virtualenv -p python3 test1`

or, if you also use virtualenvwrapper you  can do

`mkvirtualenv -p python3 test1`

Now, activate your virtualenvironment. 
Once activated you can (from inside the virtualenvironment) install ipykernel using pip:

`pip install ipykernel` (equivalent to `python -m pip install ipykernel`)

EDIT (it does not seem you need the following between parenthesis) {}

{

And now install a new kernel:

`ipython kernel install --user --name=test1`

}

At this point, you can install Jupiter by doing:

`pip install jupyter` (equivalent to `python -m pip install jupyter`)

Now start Jupiter with

`jupyter notebook`

Make sure that the kernel used is the new one. Create a new notebook.

Then if I try to run this file:

```
import matplotlib
```

You should still have the error

Go back to the terminal and do

`python -m pip install matplotlib`

And you should be good to go. I hope this will help someone else.

BONUS: 
some commands that helped me in the Jupyter notebook in understanding the situation were these:

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
! which python
! python --version
! python3 --version
! pip show matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

If running in jupyter don't forget to `pip install jupyter`.